# Why does `Int32.TryParse("1.00")` fail?

Tags: c#

I am working on a project - where i have to read the values from Excel cell and do some sort of calculation. 
Below is the code that i have tried, str denotes the values that is coming from Excel having quotation marks.- i wanted to convert this to Int for further calculation.

The problem is I am not able to convert "str" value to Integer

```
    String str ="1.00";
    str = str.Replace(@"""", @"\""");

    str = str.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    if (Int32.TryParse(str, out i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In your example str is float, not integer. Try float.TryParse instead, and if you want to get rid of quotes then use str = str.Replace(@"""", "");

Comment: As @JleruOHeP said that is not an integer, is a float or double value. Are you sure on Excel the cell is an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned it, you are trying to parse `1.00` to an `Integer`, while `1.00` is actually a `Double` datatype not an `Integer`. If you want to use integers ultimately, I suggest converting to a double first and then to an integer as such:

```
if (Double.TryParse(str, out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(i));
}
```

To remove the quotes from the string value, you can use the Substring method, as every value will have quotation marks in the beginning and the end. The method employs a `startIndex` value and the `length` of the substring to be cropped out. We can start the Substring from the second character till the `str.Length - 1` as shown below:

```
String str ="1.00";
str = str.Substring(0,(str.Length)-1); // new value of str will be 1.00
```

Comment: Your substring example would actually be .00 also it also will not compile as your substring needs to be Substring.

Comment: Just wrote directly on the site. And startIndex is zer-based so first position in the string array is 1 I think....so it should be included but I will test it and will fix. Thanks